# Why I can't apply JSON patches either direction?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to implement a way of merging JSON objects applying patches to them based on [RFC 7396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7396).

For this, I am using [JSON Merge Patch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-merge-patch) with [Pretty JSON](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prettyjson). Here is what I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var jsonmergepatch = require('json-merge-patch');
var prettyjson = require('prettyjson');
var options = {keysColor: 'blue',dashColor: 'red',stringColor: 'green'};

var entry = {
  "leaf": {
    "enabled": {
      "type": {
        "name": "string"
      },
      "id": "enabled",
      "value": "123"
    }
  },
  "id": "configuration"
};
var template = {
  "leaf": {
    "enabled": {
      "type": {
        "name": "string"
      },
      "id": "enabled",
      "value": "_"
    }
  },
  "id": "configuration"
};

var entryAppliedOnTemplate = jsonmergepatch.apply(template, entry);
var templateAppliedOnEntry = jsonmergepatch.apply(entry, template);

console.log("Entry Applied On Template:")
console.log(prettyjson.render(entryAppliedOnTemplate, options));
console.log("\nTemplate Applied On Entry:")
console.log(prettyjson.render(templateAppliedOnEntry, options));
```

Which outputs:

```
Entry Applied On Template:
leaf: 
  enabled: 
    type: 
      name: string
    id:    enabled
    value: 123
id:   configuration

Template Applied On Entry:
leaf: 
  enabled: 
    type: 
      name: string
    id:    enabled
    value: 123
id:   configuration
```

What I can't understand is that in this case the outputs are equal, and I think I am right to expect it to be not. I can't understant why my output isn't something like this:

```
Entry Applied On Template:
leaf: 
  enabled: 
    type: 
      name: string
    id:    enabled
    value: 123
id:   configuration

Template Applied On Entry:
leaf: 
  enabled: 
    type: 
      name: string
    id:    enabled
    value: _
id:   configuration
```

I can survive with that for now because the output given actually satisfies my needs at the moment. But I got confused when testing it and I want to understand what is happening here as I might get in this case on the future.

Answer (score 0):

I am dumb sometimes, I would delete this question. But I will answer it as I think someone might do the same silly mistake.

I just noticed that `jsonmergepatch.apply(source, target)` does not only return the object with a patch applied to it, but it in fact applies the patch to the real objects and return it. I was expecting it to clone it or something.